# Will Google OpenID actually return openid.pape.preferred_auth_policies?

Tags: google-openid

I am trying to get Google OpenID to return the `openid.pape.preferred_auth_policies` which are specified in the link below:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#gsa

In particular, I would like to get the `http://www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/openid-trust-level1.pdf` policy returned, but no matter what I specify in my request, Google does not seem to ever return it (and I am on a host that has a valid SSL cert). I am using simpleSAMLphp and am specifying the policies to be returned as follows (and have tried it at least 4-5 other ways, too):

```
'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0' => array(
    'max_auth_age' => 60,
    'preferred_auth_policies' => 'http://www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/openid-trust-level1.pdf', 
),
```

The request to Google looks like this:

`openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.ns.ax=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ns.ext0=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.type.ext0=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ax.type.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ax.type.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ax.type.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson&openid.ax.type.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffriendly&openid.ax.required=ext0%2Cext1%2Cext2%2Cext3%2Cext4&openid.ext0.max_auth_age=60&openid.ext0.preferred_auth_policies=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idmanagement.gov%2Fschema%2F2009%2F05%2Ficam%2Fopenid-trust-level1.pdf&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftw.socialidp.com&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftw.socialidp.com%2Fidp%2Fmodule.php%2Fopenid%2Flinkback.php%3FAuthState%<removed>https%253A%252F%252Ftw.socialidp.com%252Fidp%252Fmodule.php%252Fcore%252Fas_login.php%253FAuthId%253Dgoogleoid2%2526ReturnTo%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Ftw.socialidp.com%25252Fidp%25252Fmodule.php%25252Fcore%25252Fauthenticate.php%25253Fas%25253Dgoogleoid2%26janrain_nonce%3D2013-02-18T20%253A10%253A30Z3jP9G3&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=<removed>`

The relevant part is:

```
&openid.ext0.preferred_auth_policies=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idmanagement.gov%2Fschema%2F2009%2F05%2Ficam%2Fopenid-trust-level1.pdf
```

Can someone please verify if that is correct?

Also, at the bottom of the above referenced section of the Google OpenID page, Google states:

> The inclusion of http://www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/openid-trust-level1.pdf requires Google to assert that the authentication is in compliance with the security requirements of the GSA Profile for OpenID. These security features are provided by default on all Google authentication flows, whether or not this particular policy URL is included.

From reading that it seems like one can just blindly assume that every AuthN attempt using OpenID is at LOA1, and there really is no need to actually get this assertion back from Google. Is that a correct assumption?